# How to create macros using jinja template for salt stack

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

How to create macros using jinja template for saltstack.

Interfaces.jinja

Answer (score 1):

Macros (usually called functions in other languages) are easy to create in jinja with salt-stack.

Here is syntax to create a simple macro with parameter and a `for` loop inside,

```
{% macro my_macro(paremeter_name) %}
    {% for x in mylist.keys() -%}
        # Do Something here...
        # .....
        {{ paremeter_name }}
    {% endfor -%}
{% endmacro %}
```

Calling a macro,

```
{{ my_macro('hello') }}
```